# Pandas join only a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have dataframe A and dataframe B, I want to join B onto A but only for a certain column on B. Like this:

```py
dataA = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
A = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns=['testA'])

dataB = [['a', 1, 'asdf'], 
        ['b', 2, 'asdf'], 
        ['c', 3, 'asdf'], 
        ['d', 4, 'asdf'], 
        ['e', 5, 'asdf']]
B = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['testB', 'num', 'asdf'])

Out[1]: A
    testA
0   a
1   c
2   d
3   e

Out[2]: B
    testB   num     asdf
0   a       1       asdf
1   b       2       asdf
2   c       3       asdf
3   d       4       asdf
4   e       5       asdf
```

My current code is:

```py
Out[3]: A.join(B.set_index('testB'), on='testA')
    testA   num     asdf
0   a       1       asdf
1   c       3       asdf
2   d       4       asdf
3   e       5       asdf
```

My desired output is only to join over the 'num' column as below and ignore the 'asdf' column, or all other columns if there were even more:

```py
Out[4]: A

    testA   num 
0   a       1   
1   c       3   
2   d       4    
3   e       5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to use `merge`:

```
new_df= A.merge(B, how='left', left_on='testA', right_on='testB')[['testA', 'num']]
```

Result:

```
  testA  num
0     a    1
1     c    3
2     d    4
3     e    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`, first create a pd.Series with the column you are bringing over as values, and in the index set the "mapping" column.  This ignores and not doing any work on other columns not need in the desired result:

```
A['num'] = A['testA'].map(B.set_index('testB')['num'])
A
```

Output:

```
  testA  num
0     a    1
1     c    3
2     d    4
3     e    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using what you already have, and keeping only the columns you want.

```
z = a.join(b.set_index('testB'), on='testA')[["testA","num"]]
```

outputs:

```
    testA   num
0   a       1
1   c       3
2   d       4
3   e       5
```